# check ienumerable for any elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to check if `list` has any elements, and the way I'm doing it is with `Any()`:

```
    public static string ToQuotedString(this IEnumerable list)
    {
        if (!list.Any())
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var output = string.Empty;

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            output += "'" + item + "',";
        }

        return output.TrimEnd(',');
    }
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no accessible extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am referencing `System.Linq`:

`using System.Linq;`

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: The linq-extension-method `Any` is defined on `IEnumerable<T>`, not on `IEnumerable`.

Comment: linq generally works against `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: i'd also caution about multiple enumerations of a single `IEnumerable`

Comment: You also shouldn't be concatenating strings in a loop.  Just use `Join`, it already implemented this method correctly.

Comment: Your entire method can be written into a much more efficient: `return string.Join(",", list.Select(item => $"'{item}'"))`

Comment: or if you need to do things conditionally - use a stringbuilder.

Comment: @FrankerZ That won´t solve OPs problem, as linq only works on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameter is `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerable<T>` but the [LINQ extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods) are for the latter. So either change the type of the parameter to `IEnumerable<string>` or use [`Cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
if (!list.Cast<string>().Any())
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

If you don't know the type (`string` in this case) and you just want to know if there's at least one, you can still use `Cast` and `Any` because `Object` works always:

```
bool containsAny = list.Cast<Object>().Any();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a non-generic enumerator, the cheapest way to check for any elements is to check if there's a first element.

In this case, `hasAny` is false:

```
var collection= new List<string>( ) as IEnumerable;
bool hasAny = collection.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
```

while in this case, it's true:

```
var collection= new List<string>{"dummy"} as IEnumerable;
bool hasAny = collection.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
```